# file not found error on apache in selinux

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, selinux

I had a working client to server connection going, where my javascript ajax -> apache server on selinux worked fine.

I copied over new versions of existing php files and overwrote the old ones using sudo.

I started getting 404 errors on my requests, even thought I can see the php file executing and returning the requested information to the ajax error function, but its hidden in the responseJSON - the status="error" and the error"404 not found"

I reset the ownership and permissions using
`chown -R apache.apache /var/www/html/public/*
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/public/* -R
chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/public/data/* -R`

The php file being queried is in /var/www/html/public/ and does not need to read or write to the directory (it does make SQL calls to and AWS database though).

It has permissions of:

`-rw-r--r--. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0`

I did not change apache config files, and the code was working before. The method in the code definitely exists, I can add error_log statements anywhere in the php code and they execute. Again, I do get the correct data, its just hidden and the overall response is a 404 error.

I also tried re-starting apache & clearing my java cache and restarting my client.

I'm looking for anything else I can try.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I also did:      semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/html/public(/.*)?" 
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/public/data(/.*)?" 

restorecon -Rv /data/subvert/product_catalog